# How can i know Oracle HTTP Web server have installed on WLS 11g (10.3.6) installed in our work space?

Tags: http, webserver, weblogic11g

we are using WLS 11g(10.3.6) in our work space. is Oracle HTTP Server comes with the WLS 10.3.6 package..How can i know Oracle HTTP Server installed on our Work space? How This Web server will communicate with WLS server ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Oracle HTTP Server is shipped with the standard WebLogic instillation.  If you look at [this Oracle Support Document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/install.1111/e14260/overview.htm#CEGBDFHD) it states that you must download that software additionally and then configure WebLogic to communicate with it.